# Put your comment on my post. Put your comment at my post

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Put your comment on my post. 
Put your comment at my post.
Which one is correct?

I mean to say,  which preposition is appropriate for this sentence?

"At"or "on"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question and its title draw spam like bees to honey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. I suggest
- Post your comment on my post.

One does not *place* the comment *on* the post.  So  "on my post" is not an adverbial phrase telling *where to put* the comment.

Rather, the comment is *about* (that is, "on") your post. So "on my post" modifies "comment", telling *which comment*.

So the structure is 
Post (your comment (on my post)).
not Post (your comment) (on my post).

As for  "at", that is definitely spatial/positional.  But it's imprecise. Depending how the blog works, you might say "Post your comment *after* my post" or "Post your comment *below* my post", or even Post your comment *above* my post".

- if you have a comment on my post, [please] put it below my post.

In ELL SE, it would be "Post your comment (on my comment) below my comment, and direct it to me by prefacing it with my username and  **:**."